# How to go truly Flash-free in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, adobe-flash, html

After the Mountain Lion install I'm trying to now go Flash free. Really, *really* 100% Flash free. This is fine for 99% of content out that I access, but sadly there are some videos that I still cannot get to without Flash.

I do know about the popular [post by Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/flash_free_and_cheating_with_google_chrome), however I'm not interested in installing Chrome because (1) I hate the heavy handed way Google forces itself into your system with its hidden daemons etc. and (2) you're still installing a Flash client on your system. I don't want a Flash client, period.

I see that such solutions do exist for iOS. To name a few:

- [iSwifter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iswifter-flash-web-browser/id388857173?mt=8)
- [Cloud Browse](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-browse/id394418635?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)
- [Skyfire](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skyfire-web-browser/id384941497?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

But sadly no such options appear to exist on the Mac :( In fact iSwifter [was promised to the Mac](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-20083241-248/iswifters-flash-workaround-app-coming-to-the-mac/) earlier but there hasn't been a peep about this since.

What I'm looking for is some kind of web-based service either with a native Mac client app or simply a webapp that would:

1. Allow me to render the entire site server-side in Flash and send me the video feed in some decent app or webapp (ala iSwifter), or
2. Have some server side scraper of the swf file that finds the reference to the actual .mp4 and passes that along to you (ala Skyfire).

So far the closest thing I've found to this is ClipConverter, but sadly [its supported list of services](http://www.clipconverter.cc/about/), though decent, is nowhere near extensive enough to cover all the obscure websites that I use which all roll their own crappy swf wrapper around the mp4/flv content.

#### Examples

Some people are suggesting client-side-only approaches like ClickToFlash. These are good but the problem is that any particular Flash based video service / wrapper needs to be explicitly supported by it so by definition cannot catch 100% of all content, only a dedicated server-based Flash renderer like iSwifter can do that. Here are some concrete example videos that require Flash which most solutions don't handle:

- http://www.destructoid.com/let-s-get-physical-with-quantum-conundrum-232175.phtml
- http://www.gamespot.com/deadlight-2012/videos/video-review-deadlight-6389587/
- http://www.escapistmagazine.com/videos/view/zero-punctuation/6083-Inversion (this one has an HTML5 link but you need to pay to get in. That's plain wrong)
- http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi771138841/

Before answering, you can test your solution with the above links. Thanks!

Comment: What websites do you need to go on that uses flash AND doesn't support html5?

Comment: Tons. You'd be surprised how many websites roll their own flash video wrapper. Some example URLs to videos that show up as either plugin missing or please download Flash: [here](http://www.destructoid.com/let-s-get-physical-with-quantum-conundrum-232175.phtml), [here](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2012/07/30/building-a-sky-caper-windforge/), and [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/video/17874/seasons/seasons-boardgamegeek-origins-2012)

Comment: I don't see Gruber's way as an issue. In fact, that's really Flash free. The only daemon I see Chrome install is their autoupdate program, but that can be easily disabled.

Comment: A good comment from @XCool (voted up), but this is a great purist question – no local Flash client, full stop.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why don't you want flash?

Comment: Why does Apple, Gruber, ClickToFlash guys, or anyone want to go Flash free? Because it's a pile of crap. Also, I'm reverting the title. I don't think we need to qualify that it is without Chrome, because Chrome **does** run a local Flash client so is not "Flash free".

Comment: @kLy I'm curious about what you mean by Chrome's hidden daemons. As I mentioned, the only ones I know about is their autoupdate. Care to list the others that we may not be aware of? Thanks.

Comment: Yes the auto update. It puts it there without your permission and if you kill the file it reverts it next launch. You can disable the plist but I don't even want that file there period. The point is that this is not Windows, you shouldn't be treating your users like that adding your own auto updating crap to their system startup without even asking. It's just not on. Sorry if I'm being too purist, but as you can tell from this post in the first place, I am :)

Answer (score 3):

I use [ClickToPlugin](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/), which converts some Flash videos to HTML5 (this has the added benefit of letting you download them by right-clicking and choosing `Download Video`). It works for YouTube, at least, and for the videos on the second and third webpages you linked (though not the first).

Comment: Reading [Media data objects](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/killers.xhtml#media_data) alongside killer [Flash.js](https://github.com/hoyois/plugin-to-html5/blob/master/Flash.js) I see that a URL for Flash content may be redirected to a URL for *existing* HTML5 content, but I can't see whether/how the killer **converts** to *new HTML5 video*. Please, am I missing something? I have very little knowledge of capabilities of JavaScript.)

Comment: I have not re-visited ClickToPlugin in a while and it seems like they have a community maintained [list of converters](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/killers.xhtml#database) which is awesome! This kind of client-side implementation gets around most content but not 100%. For that we still need some server side Flash rendering to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [ClickToFlash](https://github.com/downloads/hoyois/safariextensions/ClickToFlash-2.6.9.safariextz) and [HUDTube](http://hudtu.be)? HUDTube works with 99% of the videos on YouTube, even the ones C2F misses.

Comment: Can HUDTube convert all Flash content? – there's that one percent in the question.

Comment: Yes it runs even if there is only an FLV option available in C2F (when H.264 isn't available).

Comment: HUDTube does Youtube and Vimeo. I have those covered already. What I need is something that works for everything else.

Answer (score 3):

If you truly want to go flash free, then use Safari, possibly in conjunction with an extension like [Youtube5](http://www.verticalforest.com/youtube5-extension/), which should handle some embeds that don't do html5 properly. However you're never going to get 100% of videos working. For one thing, while a majority of "flash video" is indeed a flash app playing h264 video, some of it is in other formats that Safari can't handle, including some wrapped in DRM.

You have to make a choice - do you want zero flash, or do you want a way to watch all videos? At the moment you can't have both, sorry.

Comment: Not true. As listed in my question above, it IS possible to have both. Many examples exist for iOS.